# Compiling Autoware v1.12.0 with cuda v10.2

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a pre-compiled Autoware v1.12.0 on my system which I compiled when I had Cuda 9 on my Ubuntu 16.04 system. Basic Autoware functionalities came up, but I could not utilize my GPU HW. Referring NVIDIA support pointed me to update Cuda owing to my GPU HW.  I have a Turing GPU with compute capability 7.5. NVIDIA guidelines for such hardware is to use Cuda v10.x. Accordingly I have installed Cuda v10.2 with cuDNN v7.5.x on an Ubuntu 16.04 OS. However since then, I am trying to recompile Autoware v1.12.0 which is failing at `lidar_euclidean_cluster_detect` package due to a missing file: `/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/dispatch/is_trivial_copy.h`.

Error message is:

```
No rule to make target '/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/dispatch/is_trivial_copy.h', needed by 'CMakeFiles/gpu_euclidean_clustering.dir/nodes/lidar_euclidean_cluster_detect/gpu_euclidean_clustering_generated_gpu_euclidean_clustering.cu.o'.  Stop.
```

Has anyone installed Autoware v1.12.0 with Cuda v10.x? Autoware recommends Cuda v9.0 for Autoware on OS Ubuntu 16.04, but based on my GPU HW, NVIDIA lays out requirement for Cuda v10.x. Any suggestions on how to get out of this paradox?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339693/compiling-autoware-v1.12.0-with-cuda-v10.2/) by [Abhinav](https://answers.ros.org/users/50210/abhinav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2019-12-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@Abhinav - Unfortunately, you ware working with an unsupported configuration. Autoware 1.12.0 supports both Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04. However, when using Ubuntu 16.04, it only works correctly with CUDA 9.0. Since your computing hardware is not supported by CUDA 9, you cannot use this combination of hardware and software. Your best bet is to upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 and try compiling there with CUDA 10.0 (not 10.1 or 10.2). See the compatibility matrix here: https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/autoware/-/wikis/Source-Build

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2019-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abhinav](https://answers.ros.org/users/50210/abhinav/) on 2020-01-15**:
Using the pipeline you suggested, I am able to compile AW  v1.12 successfully. Thanks @Josh

Please let me know if any of the more recent releases (v1.13 or v1.14) are significant improvements and tested for stability since using Ubuntu 18.04 now opens that horizon for me.